# "This source file has changed. It no longer matches…" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a primary project which refers to DLL of a secondary project. I changed some code in secondary project, built it and changed the DLL reference in the primary project to the updated DLL.

Now, in VS 2010, when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> to try and debug the updated code from the secondary project, it shows the following error and takes me to the old code when I press OK.

> This source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the
>   file used to build the application being debugged.

[image]

I have tried Clean+Build, Rebuild, cleared temporary files etc. I checked the properties of the DLL and its path points to the newer version(updated code). But the problem still persists.

In short, VS is completely ignoring the new code. Any clues how to resolve it?

Comment: If both projects are in same solution you have to reference *project* (not dll).

Comment: Try deleting the `.vs` folder and then running your project again.

Comment: Why do you have 2 versions of the source code? when it "takes me to the old code" what file path is that in?

Comment: It tells you that the DLL that actually got loaded isn't the one that you changed.  Use Debug > Windows > Modules to find out where it came from, beware the GAC and manually copying DLLs.  Fuslogvw.exe can be helpful.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes sir. Both projects are from different solutions and hence the dll.

Comment: @RahulSharma tried deleting the `.vs` folder. Didn't work.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks sir. This is a new learning for me. The dll was coming from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.x\Temporary ASP .Net Files\...`. I deleted all these files, rebuild both the solutions. Still the same issue.

Comment: @HansPassant I suspect that there is another dll that is referring the old version as a dependency. Is there a way to know which dlls are being used as a dependency by other dlls?